# Dependency conflict between 'setup_requires' and 'install_requires' in Python package

Tags: python, setuptools

I came across an error when trying to install and test my package.

The error was caused by conflicting versions of transitive dependencies of two packages - one in `setup_requires` (`twine`) and another in `install_requires` (`tensorflow`).

Both transitively depend on `bleach`, each with a different version.

Installing the package with `pip install -e .` or `python setup.py develop` works as expected.

When running `python setup.py test`, an error occurs (note: this happens only when running tests *after* installing. If the package was not installed first, there is no error).

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 3, in <module>
    setup()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 145, in setup
    return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 955, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py", line 974, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/root/test/.eggs/pytest_runner-4.4-py3.6.egg/ptr.py", line 189, in run
    with self.project_on_sys_path():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/contextlib.py", line 81, in __enter__
    return next(self.gen)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/test.py", line 166, in project_on_sys_path
    require('%s==%s' % (ei_cmd.egg_name, ei_cmd.egg_version))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 900, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 791, in resolve
    raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
pkg_resources.ContextualVersionConflict: (bleach 3.1.0 (/root/test/.eggs/bleach-3.1.0-py3.6.egg), Requirement.parse('bleach==1.5.0'), {'tensorboard'})
```

#### Steps to reproduce

I get the error with this minimal package structure:

```
my-package
|-- src/
|    |-- module.py (empty)
|-- setup.py
|-- setup.cfg
```

setup.cfg looks like this:

```
[metadata]
name = test
version = 0.0.1

[options]
package_dir=
    = src

packages=find:

setup_requires =
    setuptools >= 40.0.0
    pip >= 10
    pytest-runner >= 2.0
    twine >= 1.0.0

install_requires =
    tensorflow == 1.6.0


tests_require =
    pytest >=3.0, <4.0

[options.packages.find]
where=src

[aliases]
test=pytest
```

setup.py look like this:

```
from setuptools import setup

setup()
```

Steps:

1. Run `pip install -e .`
2. Run `python setup.py test`

Environment:

- `python:3.6` Docker image

#### What I think is happening

As far as I can tell, when running the commands (both installing and testing), packages from `setup_requires` are installed and egg files are placed in .eggs directory.

When running `python setup.py test`, setuptools installs all packages from `install_requires` but sees that there is already an egg for one of the dependencies and uses that.

I'm not sure what the exact mechanism is.

#### Possible solutions

- Use newer version of tensorflow. This solved the conflict
- Or: remove `twine` from `setup_requires` - I realised it is not required for setup
- Or: Do not install the package locally. Only run `python setup.py test`

#### Questions

Although I was able to solve the problem in this specific case, I would still like to know more about what caused it in the first place.

- At what point is the .eggs directory created?
- Why the install works fine but tests fail?
- Why tests fail only *after* install?
- Is there a way to prevent the conflict from happening?

Comment: You have met a case of dependency hell. `tensorflow==1.6.0` requires `tensorboard==1.6.0` which requires `bleach==1.5.0`. Your setup reqs contain `twine` which requires `readme-renderer` which requires `bleach>=2.1.0`, so you basically can't install your package for development. The error comes up on tests because `pytest-runner` installs all setup dependencies to generate the egg info metadata.